# What is `app` property when access child firebase database (javascript)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

This is my file that initialize firebase:

```
export default class {
  static parent = RNFirebase.initializeApp();
  static child = null;

  constructor() {
    child = this.parent.database('child-database-url');
  }
}
```

In another file I use this as:

```
import FDBS from '../initializer';

FDBS.child.app.database().ref('orders').once("value", data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And this line of code confuse me: `FDBS.child.app.database().ref(` actually `.app`.
Why I need to access this property to get data actually what I am trying to get is to be able to write code like: `FDBS.child.database().ref('orders').once(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, let's fix your syntax error regarding the "static" variables in your `initializer.js` file. Instead of using a class for such a simple data structure, just export an object.

```
import RNFirebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/database';

// inits & returns the default FirebaseApp instance
const parent = RNFirebase.initializeApp(); // or RNFirebase.app() if initialized automatically

// gets a FirebaseDatabase instance that points to 'child-database-url'
const child = parent.database('child-database-url');

export default {
  parent, // this is a FirebaseApp object
  child   // this is a FirebaseDatabase object
}
```

Now, as shown in the above snippet, your `parent` object is an instance of the [`FirebaseApp`](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/app/firebaseapp) object and the `child` object is an instance of the [`FirebaseDatabase`](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/database) object.

In your code that loads in `FDBS`, you access `FDBS.child.app` ([reference](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/database#app)) which returns the `FirebaseApp` object associated with that instance of `FirebaseDatabase` - in your case this object is `FDBS.parent`.

As the two objects have different types, I recommend choosing to export either two `FirebaseApp` instances or two `FirebaseDatabase` instances.

### Export `FirebaseApp` instances

Based on your question, you seem to be expecting that the `child` object is also a `FirebaseApp` object because you want to call `FDBS.child.database().ref(...)`.

```
import RNFirebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/database';

const parent = RNFirebase.initializeApp(/* config */); // or RNFirebase.app()
const child = RNFirebase.initializeApp({
  ...parent.options, // copies everything from the default app's configuration
  databaseURL: 'child-database-url' // but overwrites the value of databaseURL
});

export default {
  parent, // this is a FirebaseApp object that uses the default "parent" database
  child   // this is a FirebaseApp object that uses the "child" database
}
```

You would use this as follows:

```
import FDBS from '../initializer';

FDBS.child.database().ref('orders').once("value", data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

This approach introduces a problem when you involve authentication. If a user signs into your app, they will be signed in for the default FirebaseApp instance but not the one used by `FDBS.child` (unless you explicitly do so). Because of this I recommend the other approach.

### Export `FirebaseDatabase` instances (recommended)

```
import RNFirebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/database';

const defaultApp = RNFirebase.initializeApp(/* config */); // or RNFirebase.app()

const dbParent = defaultApp.database();
const dbChild = defaultApp.database('child-database-url');

export default {
  // app: defaultApp, // (if you want to export the FirebaseApp object too)
  parent: dbParent, // this is a FirebaseDatabase object that points to the default "parent" database
  child: dbChild    // this is a FirebaseDatabase object that points to the "child" database
}
```

You would use this as follows:

```
import FDBS from '../initializer';

FDBS.child.ref('orders').once("value", data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

---

**Note:** Don't forget to handle errors. I encourage using promises rather than callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit in response to your comment

You don't show where RNFirebase comes from, but you should be able to access your database like

`let initapp = RNFirebase.initializeApp()`
 `let db = initapp.database('url')`
 `db.ref....`

Right now you've done that in a roundabout way

> child = this.parent.database(

And if you check how you define parent, it's basically like the snippet I provided above.

So you could just be a little bit more concise less circular.

--

From the official docs, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database#app

> The app associated with the Database service instance.

Where app has on it the database property, among others https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#database

> Gets the Database service for the current app.  Example

```
var database = app.database();
// The above is shorthand for:
// var database = firebase.database(app);
```

Comment: So in my code is that ok to access child db or it can be improved somehow?